# SIMD code for transforming one-letter amino acid code into integer between 0 and 22

Tags: c++, x86-64, simd

Trying to code the following transformation in SIMD C++, any ideas ?

Code is from https://github.com/soedinglab/hh-suite/blob/master/src/hhutil-inl.h#L45-L83

```
const int ANY=20;       //number representing an X (any amino acid) internally
const int GAP=21;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Transforms the one-letter amino acid code into an integer between 0 and 22
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
inline char aa2i(char c)
{
  //A  R  N  D  C  Q  E  G  H  I  L  K  M  F  P  S  T  W  Y  V
  if (c>='a' && c<='z') c+='A'-'a';
  switch (c)
    {
    case 'A': return 0;
    case 'R': return 1;
    case 'N': return 2;
    case 'D': return 3;
    case 'C': return 4;
    case 'Q': return 5;
    case 'E': return 6;
    case 'G': return 7;
    case 'H': return 8;
    case 'I': return 9;
    case 'L': return 10;
    case 'K': return 11;
    case 'M': return 12;
    case 'F': return 13;
    case 'P': return 14;
    case 'S': return 15;
    case 'T': return 16;
    case 'W': return 17;
    case 'Y': return 18;
    case 'V': return 19;
    case 'X': return ANY;
    case 'J': return ANY;
    case 'O': return ANY;
    case 'U': return 4;  //Selenocystein -> Cystein
    case 'B': return 3;  //D (or N)
    case 'Z': return 6;  //E (or Q)
    case '-': return GAP;
    case '.': return GAP;
    case '_': return GAP;
    }
  if (c>=0 && c<=32) return -1; // white space and control characters
  return -2;
}
```

Comment: Which SIMD? It looks feasible with SSSE3 (a bit annoying, but with several `pshufb`'s sure, why not). I hope you have at least 16 `c`'s to do this on though, it's not very useful to apply SIMD to just one `c`.

Comment: x86-64 simd, will have tens of thousands of `c`

Comment: Presumably you want to accelerate this transcoding. But is this your real bottleneck ? At least, turn the switch statement to an array lookup.

Comment: Are `ANY` and `GAP` special constants? If so what value? Or can `ANY` literally return arbitrary values?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: clang already does compile the switch into an array lookup, after a range-check and checking an immediate bitmap.  https://godbolt.org/z/fK9Eqnzeb  But GCC actually uses a jump table, so yes, manually using an array would be better if you're willing to hard code more ASCII facts like that the lowest value is `'-'`, so `arr[c - '-']` with the array initialized accordingly.  One change I'd make is `c &= ~0x20` instead of the conditional add for `toupper`, if that doesn't make any of `-` `.` or `_` indistinguishable from other inputs.  (Check for control characters *first*.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: there is no reason to rely on the compiler doing the transformation. A lookup-table is cleaner. Can even be on all 256 input values.

Comment: ANY = 20, GAP = 21, updated code sample.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: It's more reliably/portably efficient, but it's not "cleaner" in terms of readable source code.  I was still editing my previous comment to make that point when you replied.  You have to figure out which input has the lowest ASCII code so you can do `static const char LUT[] = { ['-'] = GAP, ['A'-'-'] = 0, etc. };` if you can use C99(?) designated-initializer syntax, otherwise even more of the initializer depends on comments to keep track of position.  And you'd want to do `LUT[c - '-']` after manual range-checks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Also you need to init all the "unused" positions to `-1` so designated-initializer syntax maybe doesn't help.

Comment: The OP uses return codes -1 and -2 for some reason. Everything in the LUT, input argument unsigned char, no range check. Can add an EBCDIC LUT for mainframers.

Comment: code is from https://github.com/soedinglab/hh-suite/blob/master/src/hhutil-inl.h#L45-L83

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Oh, just a 256-entry LUT?  Yeah you could do that, then you don't need any range-check.  If the caller was already going to branch on the return value being negative, like using the `-2` or `-1` to print an error message, we can keep the LUT smaller and do part of error checking with range checks, which optimize into the same error branches when this inlines.  Or at least maybe keep the parts that need to stay hot in the non-error cases in one fewer cache line.

Comment: @PeterCordes: anyway, my feeling is that all these optimizations are of little use, compared to what this application computes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Turning it into a range-check and a smaller table is of course useful when looking at how one might do it with AVX-512VBMI `vpermb` (perhaps using 32-byte vectors if the rest of the program doesn't aggressively use 64-byte vectors.)  Or even with multiple SSSE3 or AVX2 `pshufb`.  But sure, the optimizations I was describing on a `char LUT[]` are pretty minor.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I mean, optimizing this transcoding probably yields marginal gains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one idea using AVX2, the "main" idea is using VPSHUFB in "lookup table"-mode (using the data as the shuffle mask, with the LUT as the first source operand). The rest of the code basically deals with all the special cases.

For range checks, I shift the range up (by adding some constant) to make the top of the range = 127, then compare whether the resulting value is signed-greater-than some lower bound (the old lower bound, plus however much the range was shifted by).

I rely on VPSHUFB's property that it puts 0 in a byte if the top bit of its shuffle index is set. By first shifting the range down so that the start of the range lands on zero, and then up with an unsigned-saturating addition so that everything above the end of the range (thanks to the subtraction, anything outside the range is now above the end of the range) has its upper bit set, so the result of the lookup-by-shuffle will be zero there. That means I can OR the results together instead of having to blend them.

Perhaps some of this can be simplified, especially the handling of the special cases.

BTW I tested this somewhat (not rigorously), and it seemed to work for non-negative characters at least. For negative characters, -1 isn't handled the same way, which would be fixable but I expected that no one cares about `(char)-1`.

Handling any "leftovers" (if `N` is not divisible by 32) is done by having a special extra iteration that overlaps partially with the second-to-last iteration, unless `N` is so small that that would access memory before the start of the data.

`in` and `out` do not require any special alignment, and can be equal, but the input and output shouldn't overlap in some odd way.

```
void aa2i(char *in, char *out, size_t N)
{
    size_t i = 0;

    __m256i LUT1 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    //   @  A  B  C  D  E   F  G  H  I    J   K   L   M  N    O
        -2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 6, 13, 7, 8, 9, ANY, 11, 10, 12, 2, ANY,
        -2, 0, 3, 4, 3, 6, 13, 7, 8, 9, ANY, 11, 10, 12, 2, ANY);
    __m256i LUT2 = _mm256_setr_epi8(
    //   P  Q  R   S   T  U   V   W    X   Y  Z   [   \   ]   ^    _
        14, 5, 1, 15, 16, 4, 19, 17, ANY, 18, 6, -2, -2, -2, -2, GAP,
        14, 5, 1, 15, 16, 4, 19, 17, ANY, 18, 6, -2, -2, -2, -2, GAP);
    do {
        for (; i + 31 < N; i += 32)
        {
            __m256i data = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*) & in[i]);
            // is above ws but not letter
            __m256i is_above_ws = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_add_epi8(data, _mm256_set1_epi8(95)), _mm256_set1_epi8(94));
            // is control
            __m256i is_control = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_add_epi8(data, _mm256_set1_epi8(64)), _mm256_set1_epi8(96));
            // is '-' or '.'
            __m256i is_dash_or_dot = _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_add_epi8(data, _mm256_set1_epi8(81)), _mm256_set1_epi8(125));
            // convert '`'-'z' to '@'-'Z'
            __m256i is_not_a_to_z_lower =
                _mm256_cmpgt_epi8(_mm256_sub_epi8(data, _mm256_set1_epi8('`' - 128)), _mm256_set1_epi8(26));
            __m256i lowercase = _mm256_xor_si256(data, _mm256_andnot_si256(is_not_a_to_z_lower, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x20)));
            // range @ .. O
            __m256i rangeA = _mm256_sub_epi8(lowercase, _mm256_set1_epi8('@'));
            __m256i partA = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(LUT1, _mm256_adds_epu8(rangeA, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x70)));
            // range P .. _
            __m256i rangeB = _mm256_sub_epi8(lowercase, _mm256_set1_epi8('P'));
            __m256i partB = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(LUT2, _mm256_adds_epu8(rangeB, _mm256_set1_epi8(0x70)));
            // assemble parts
            __m256i res = _mm256_or_si256(partA, partB);
            res = _mm256_blendv_epi8(res, _mm256_set1_epi8(-2), _mm256_add_epi8(data, _mm256_set1_epi8(1)));
            res = _mm256_or_si256(res, _mm256_or_si256(is_above_ws, _mm256_and_si256(is_control, _mm256_set1_epi8(-2))));
            res = _mm256_blendv_epi8(res, _mm256_set1_epi8(GAP), is_dash_or_dot);
            _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*) & out[i], res);
        }
        if (i < N && N >= 32)
        {
            // if there is a leftover but the array is big enough,
            // do one last iteration for the leftover, partly overlapping with the previous iteration
            i = N - 32;
        }
        else 
            break;
    } while (1);

    // scalar fallback, only used for tiny arrays
    for (; i < N; i++)
        out[i] = aa2i(in[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If question is for x86-64 following code should do the work. For better readability it is in assembler, but with small changes could be changed to C with intrinsics.

```
use64

; rcx - pointer to char
; return result in rax

push            rbx
vpbroadcastb    ymm0, [rcx]             ; broadcast the byte to every byte in ymm0
vpcmpeqb        ymm1, ymm0, [casesLow]  ; compare against lowercase chars
vpcmpeqb        ymm2, ymm0, [casesHi]   ; compare against uppercase chars
vpor            ymm1, ymm1, ymm2        ; combine results of both comparisons 
vpmovmskb       eax, ymm1               ; if anything matches then eax will be nonzero
bsf             eax, eax                ; scan the lowest set bit -> index of match
jz              notFound                ; if eax was 0 (no match) bsf sets ZF... so jump
lea             rbx, [mapped]           ; load the mapping address
movsx           rax, byte [rbx + rax]   ; sign extend the byte from mapping
pop             rbx
ret

notFound:
mov             al, [rcx]               ; load char to check bounds
test            al, 0xE0                ; by AND-ing with mask 11100000
setz            al                      ; if result is zero then char is within [0,32) so set to 1
sub             rax, 2                  ; make 1 -> -1 and 0 -> -2
pop             rbx
ret

casesLow:
db  'arndcqeghilkmfpstwyvxjoubz-._', 32, 0, 0
casesHi:
db  'ARNDCQEGHILKMFPSTWYVXJOUBZ-._', 0, 0, 0
mapped:
db  0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,20,20,4,3,6,21,21,21,-1,-1,-1
```

Note that 32 [space] is mapped within lowercase to -1, in order the `test al, 0xE0` to work.

If you already know the lower/upper case of the char you can skip one of the `vpcmpeqb` and the `vpor`.

Comment: This is doing one character at a time, spending multiple instructions on it.  This won't be faster than `movzx eax, byte [rcx]` / `movsx eax, byte [LUT + rax]`, using one 256-byte lookup table (4 cache lines).  That can handle 1 byte per clock cycle on Intel before Alder Lake, AMD before Zen 3.  (Zen3 / Alder Lake can run 3 loads per clock, so 1.5 characters per clock cycle in a simple C loop.)

Comment: Even if you consider an intrinsics version of this that can keep the constants in vector regs throughout the loop, and wouldn't save/restore RBX every character (for no reason; could have used RDX), you're basically spending a bunch of instructions to make your LUT slightly smaller.  You do still do a LUT lookup with a `movsx` load.  by constrast, Harold's answer spends about 24 instructions per 32 bytes of input, and the majority of them are single-uop, so it may run something like 3 bytes per cycle, vs. 1 for simple scalar LUT or maybe 0.5 for yours.

Comment: Thanks, i implemented very similar algorithm, in c# 2 days ago,
disassembly: https://github.com/lydonchandra/PerfRefactor1/blob/0f854110c209bb49c33b03a885400f0c4d39971c/Bio/Dna/DnaLib/CompressSimd.txt#L45-L52

c# code
  https://github.com/lydonchandra/PerfRefactor1/blob/0f854110c209bb49c33b03a885400f0c4d39971c/Bio/Dna/DnaLib/Class1.cs#L123-L170

worst case scenario, it is ONLY 20% faster, but on typical protein input, it is up to 7x faster

currently trying to benchmark Harold's answer

Comment: @LydonCh: why the conditional `if (protAa >= (byte)'a')` before masking to upper case?  If you check for out-of-range first, like `protA < 'A'`, then the common case can unconditionally AND.  Or like this answer, unconditionally `vpor` to make lower-case (or `vpand` to make upper) instead of comparing twice and ORing the results.  2 instructions instead of 3.  But not a big difference, and if you're looping over many AAs, just making the LUT bigger will be a win.  128 bytes (2 cache lines) can easily stay hot in cache.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, what do you mean by `checking out-of-range first, like protA < 'A' ` then the common case can unconditionally AND? 
 benchmarking `vpor` now to see how much does it speed up :-)

Comment: @LydonCh: I mean `if (protA < 'A') { if (protA <= 32) return -1; else more checks; }` near the top of the function since the common case is that `protA >= 'A'`.  If that `if` doesn't run, then `protA &= ~0x20;` and broadcast.  (Or better, broadcast and then SIMD `or`, to encourage the compiler to broadcast directly from memory, separate from loading into an integer reg.)  Or if gaps are not rare, that might not work as well since `'-' = 0x2d`.  In that case just use a 128 or 256-entry LUT if you don't want to use Harold's implementation to go faster than 1 AA per clock cycle.

Comment: @LydonCh: The basis of that suggestion is that if you're going to branch on anything, separate the common case that you can handle fast (with compare/movemask/tzcnt) vs. all the exceptions.  But really this is pointless; a 128 or 256-entry LUT of `byte`s is still small and will stay hot in cache while looping over a sequence, and makes it unnecessary to do any branching unless you want to throw an error.  (Checking if the LUT result is negative might be the cheapest way to do that.)  Broadcasting a single byte to a SIMD register is never going to beat a simple LUT for 1 char at a time.

Comment: ahh got it now, early return, thanks @PeterCordes

Comment: @LydonCh: Over large arrays, harold's answer should be at least 3x faster on modern Intel/AMD (like Skylake or Zen 2 or later) than the best case for a 256-byte LUT (1 or 1.5 AAs per cycle) where the asm is `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` / `movsx eax, byte [rbx + rax]`; a larger table spends a bit of cache footprint to save all that SIMD work in the loop.  Indexing instead of comparing is more efficient if you're going to go one byte at a time.